# Overriding curly braces in React to allow for LaTeX parsing

Tags: reactjs, latex, mathjax

Simple question. I'm trying to render LaTeX with MathJax in a React component. For grouped sub/super-scripts - for example, `X_{foo}` - the curly braces are taken to be JSX, and react says `foo not defined`.

Simple workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Any javascript expressions in your JSX needs to be wrapped in curly braces. Try: `{X_{foo}}` rather than `X_{foo}`

Comment: Doesn't work. `Unexpected token (20:207)`.

The code looks like: `\({X_{foo}}\)`, where `\(` and `\)` are the Mathjax inline LaTeX delimiters.

Comment: JSX is a JavaScript syntax extension that looks similar to XML. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html  To use a JavaScript expression in your JSX, wrap the entire expression in a pair of curly braces.

Comment: I am not familiar with Mathjax or where you are using it, but if you are using a Mathjax expression inside your JSX, the whole expression will need to be wrapped in curly braces. Eg:   `<div someProp={ \(X_{foo}\) } / >`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any react-mathjax package?

For example, I am using [react-mathjax2](https://github.com/wko27/react-mathjax) npm package. Then I am able to render MathJax expressions by surrounding them with single quotation marks or escaping them by double backslash like this:

```
const eXY = 'e=\\{x,y\\}';
const Pxy = 'P_{xy}';
```

Example for inline display of LaTeX without delimiters:

```
import MathJax from 'react-mathjax2'

return (
    <div>
        <MathJax.Context input='tex'>
            <div>
                Inline math formula with one expression: 
                <MathJax.Node inline>{'e=\\{x,y\\}'}</MathJax.Node> 
                and another: <MathJax.Node inline>{'P_{xy}'}</MathJax.Node>
            </div>
        </MathJax.Context>
    </div>
);
```